# Do you need to VACUUM SORT on Redshift Materialized Views?

Tags: amazon-redshift, bigdata

I can not seem to find any documentation that indicates how the sort order of an incrementally updated materialized view is maintained. Based on the lack of docs I assume this is just taken care of on REFRESH.

Does anyone know if you should be running VACUUM SORT on views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do so, to be safer. On [Materialized View Refresh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/materialized-view-refresh.html) docummentation it also mentions that the autorefresh can be automatically stopped by Redshift internal processes. We can also see some misleading information such as the `vacuum_sort_benefit` column for that view being NULL.

But after running the `vacuum sort only my-mv-view`, where `my-mv-view` is the name returned on `svv_table_info` it showed that got improvements on its sort.

It is also suggested to vacuum Postgresql materialized views due frozen ids; this behaviour are on versions after 9.4. More on the [Routine Vacuuming](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND) at Postgres Official Page.

I hope this helps!

Cheers!